# Scrollable cover like the verge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so the verge does this effect with its into images.

http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/21/5307992/inside-the-mind-of-a-fanboy

I have tried a bunch of things but am at a loss on how to implement it as I am looking to do a similar effect.

Any help or anything that will put me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Because I DIDNT make this clear I am aware of Skrollr which is what Vox Media seems to use across its verticals.

Comment: So You Want the image flip effect??

Comment: Yes, though I think its more of like a slide then a flip but yeah anything or any direction you can throw me towards would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Lame question, man. Do some research for chrissakes – I took a look at the code in dev tools as I scrolled the page, and noticed what was changing... There's a div with a class "skrollable" in it that has changing, inline values. Google searched "skrollable" and it appears they're using a plugin called skrollr. [github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

Seriously, not to break your bawls here, bright guy, but come on – that's not hard to figure out.

Comment: While thanks for that pointing me in that direction I had already found that and tried implementing it the way they did but I cant seem to get it to work how they have it which is why Im coming back here to ask the question.

Comment: Sure yeah, clearly you knew that. Look, here's a tutorial I found AGAIN through Google Search: [ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/). The technique is mad simple. Check out point #5 – curtain effect. You can teach yourself this – you're not posting a specific question; seems like you want someone to teach you something you haven't even tried learning yourself yet. Don't be lazy, Bro.